# Limiting changes to MTIME and CTIME on Linux/EXT4

Tags: linux, security, filesystems

I suspect it isn't possible, but maybe I'm missing something -

At the OS/filesystem level is it possible to prevent non-root accounts from creating/modifying files with a date in the past?

My specific use case is that I have a malware scanner scanning a huge number of users files, which is becoming onerous, and I'm looking for ways to decrease the amount of work the scanner needs to do.  I posit that if I can limit scans to files which have been changed or modified since the last run I can greatly reduce the number of files which need to be checked.

The users don't have shell or root access to the system, and if they did it would be game-over anyway, so I'm not worried about root accounts.

Its not ideal, but if necessary I can put the data on a new block device, possibly using a different kind of filesystem, or provided the overheads are not to high I am open to using an overlay filesystem.

Comment: There will be very few files with a mtime or ctime in the future.

Comment: I think his point is that files should always be marked as modified or changed in the present, not a tick more, or less. ... so malware could not sneak by by arbitrarily setting its file dates back before the prior scan.

Comment: @frankthomas Im not worried about my system being compromised - im aware that anything that can get that can get  root access or better can hide and make any check ineffective. What I dont want is code running as Apache or a user to be able to hide the actual date the file was written or modified.   I understand that by default touch can modify the ctime/mtime and thus expect other software can to. Ideally these should be set to be locked to the time the change was made.

Comment: so I've had the feeling that a solution like the one you are looking for would be a framework on the scale of selinux. It looks like the tripwire product is able to detect files that have had their timestamps set inappropriately, but it also looks like a big install. what do you think? https://opensource.com/article/18/1/securing-linux-filesystem-tripwire

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you for the thought, but I don't think Tripwire is right.  (It does periodic checking - the exact thing I'm wanting to avoid!)